# How to compare and store strings to a database of strings, for common combinations?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, string-comparison

I have a whole bunch of fixed length strings (length of maybe 100 characters each), that I want to compare with each other to find the most common character combinations between all the strings.

What would be a good way to compare each new string to the database of strings already collected? And then what would be a good way to store the results, and the string into the database? What kind of data structure would suit this?

I did tag the question "ruby", but I think it is pretty generic, so looking for anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that for these 3 strings:

> abc
>   bcd
>   cde

you want get the following output:

```
a   - 1
b   - 2
c   - 3
d   - 2
e   - 1
ab  - 1
bc  - 2
cd  - 2
de  - 1
abc - 1
bcd - 1
cde - 1
```

Then I would recommend a **TRIE** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and to store the number of appearances of each character-group in its nodes (adding 1 for every new match found).

The algorithm could then be quite easy

Start with 'abc' and while you traverse the tree (optionally creating new nodes) add 1 to every node visited, then continue with 'bc' and then with 'c'. And the same with 'bcd'. Go for 'bcd', 'cd', 'd'

While traversing the tree and adding 1 to each node visited you should cover all the doubles, triples etc.

Hope it helps, rezna